# Select drop down menu does not work in mobile and ipad view when apply bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <select>
        <option value="A3">A3</option>
        <option value="A4">A4</option>                
        <option value="A5">A5</option>   
    </select>
 </div>
```

above code is not working and also I'm try deference code[Visit](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9092/).but it's  not to working properly.

please help me!thank you.
I need a good solution.

Comment: this might help https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2975

Comment: I will advice you to use recent version of bootstrap, as it will come with all bug fixes fixes

Answer (score 1):

In the 2.1.0 version of the code (bootstrap-dropdown.js v2.1.0) `touchstart.dropdown.data-api` is already included in most of the `.on()` bindings. All you have to do is remove `touchstart.dropdown.data-api` from the html binding for clearMenus, it's near the bottom of the file.

Change

```
$('html')
  .on('click.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
```

To

```
$('html')
  .on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
```

It's just clearing any menu when you touch anywhere in the document.

[Reference](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2975)